# Set Foreign Key Column In Child Table To Null If Parent Foreign Key Deleted

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have an SQLite database.

I have learned how to insert a foreign key and now I would like to do this:
1. Delete the row which contains the foreign key in the parent table
2. Have any other table which references that foreign key set to null.

I have read about cascading deletes but that seems to delete any row which had that foreign key. Instead, I want to just null the value in any table that has a column value referencing the foreign key.

Can you advise what I can do to do this and perhaps what the terminology is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL, it sounds like you want to declare your foreign key constraint

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

I'm not as familiar with sqllite, but `ON DELETE SET NULL` is mentioned in...

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: Yes this looks exactly what I need. Do you know I can add this to an existing table? All the examples cover setting this on table creation

Comment: @Aggressor Comments are not for asking new questions. If you want to know how to change a constraint in an existing table, edit your question, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Add this where you create foreign key constraint